# Change the jquery slider position by an input change (keyup)

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, continuous-integration, slider

I'm trying to change the jQuery slider position not by sliding but by an input change:

Have a look at my code:

HTML slider input

```
<input class="range-slider-single" type="text" id="width_range" data-slider-min="350" data-slider-max="6260" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="850" data-value="850" value="850">
```

HTML input

```
<input type="text" id="width" class="form-control text-center" value="850">
```

JS / jQuery

To call the slider

```
$(".range-slider-single").slider();

$(".range-slider").slider({
    formatter: function(value) {
        return currencyAttr + ThousandSeparator(parseInt(value[0])) + " - " + currencyAttr + ThousandSeparator(parseInt(value[1]));
    }
});
```

The change to the input via the slider:

```
$("#width_range").on("slide, change", function(slideEvt) {
     $("#width").val(slideEvt.value.newValue);
});
```

And to change the slider via the input

```
$("#width").keyup(function() {
     $("#width_range").slider("value" , $(this).val())
});
```

However the last step I get the error ""no such method 'value' for slider instance"" from bootstrap-slider.min.js:4

It seems that I can't change the value of the slider via the input, because (maybe) I used attributes to define min and max value??

Comment: Better to verify jquery file version you are using

Answer (score 0):

Found the selution.

I was calling the slider before hand.

Code updated:

```
$("#width_range").on("slide, change", function(slideEvt) {
   $("#width").val(slideEvt.value.newValue);
});
$("#height_range").on("slide, change", function(slideEvt) {
    $("#height").val(slideEvt.value.newValue);
});

$('#width').on('input', function() {
    width_range.slider('setValue', $(this).val())
});
$('#height').on('input', function() {
    height_range.slider('setValue', $(this).val())
});
```

Comment: The events param in `on()` splits the string passed by spaces. Your code will run on two events: `slide,` and `change`. There is not such event as `slide,`. you should replace it with `.on("slide change", function(){...})` if you want that code to also run on `slide` event (not only on `change`). If you only want it to run on `change`, remove the `slide, ` part.